# pyradiomic reshaping masks and image.nii

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to reshaping my masks and images from almost 200 strokes patients (all nifti) before radiomics feature extraction.
Problem here is : i'm not sure that my method is correct with doing these steps :
get the origin from the image, Get the directions from image and then reshaping from the image (images can be 256,256,160). And then reshaping the whole object to fit 256,256,256.

> ```
> `for patient_folder in tqdm(os.listdir(patient_path)):
> if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(patient_path, patient_folder)):
> \#---------------------------------------------------------------------#
> Récupération du nom du patient du masque et de l'image
> patient_name = patient_folder.split("\_")\[0\]
> if os.path.exists(os.path.join(patient_path, patient_folder, "T1_nuu.nii")):
> image_path = os.path.join(patient_path, patient_folder, "T1_nu.nii")
> elif os.path.exists(os.path.join(patient_path,patient_folder, "T1.nii")):
> image_path = os.path.join(patient_path, patient_folder, "T1.nii")
> else:
> continue
>
> mask_path = os.path.join(patient_path, patient_folder, "masque_nii.nii.gz")
> image = sitk.ReadImage(image_path)
> mask = sitk.ReadImage(mask_path)
>
> Extraction des masques spécifiques à chaque région du cerveau ciblées
>
> for label_value in labels:
> part = df_bp['Label'][label_value]
> binary_mask = sitk.BinaryThreshold(mask,
> lowerThreshold=label_value,
> upperThreshold=label_value,
> insideValue=1,
> outsideValue=0)
>
> binary_masks=binary_mask
> combined_mask = binary_masks
>
> Récupération des "couleurs" par superposition des masques initiaux et combinés
> masked_image = sitk.Mask(mask, combined_mask)
> masked_im = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(masked_image)
>             #---------------------------------------------------------------------#
> Charger les images à l'aide de SimpleITK et les convertir en float32
> image = sitk.Cast(sitk.ReadImage(image_path), sitk.sitkFloat32)
> mask2 = sitk.Cast(masked_image, sitk.sitkFloat32)
>             #---------------------------------------------------------------------#
>
>             #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
> Redimensionner le masque pour qu'il corresponde à la taille de l'image            
> mask2.SetOrigin(image.GetOrigin())
> mask2.SetDirection(image.GetDirection())
> mask2.SetSpacing(image.GetSpacing())
>
>
> Vérifier si l'image et le masque ont des dimensions différentes de 256, 256, 256
> if image.GetSize() != (256, 256, 256):
> image = sitk.Resample(image, (256, 256, 256), sitk.Transform(), sitk.sitkLinear, image.GetOrigin(), (1, 1, 1), image.GetDirection(), 0.0, image.GetPixelID())
> if mask2.GetSize() != (256, 256, 256):
> mask2 = sitk.Resample(mask2, (256, 256, 256), sitk.Transform(), sitk.sitkLinear, mask2.GetOrigin(), (1, 1, 1), mask2.GetDirection(), 0.0, mask2.GetPixelID())`
> ```

Comment: Please ensure code is in a runnable state (comments are commented out) and use the stackoverflow editor's built-in toolbar for code formatting